# How to set up code coverage and unit tests for express functions?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, coffeescript, mocha.js

I have a route defined like

`app.post '/v1/media', authentication.hasValidApiKey, multipart, mediaController.create, mediaController.get`

I want to write tests for the individual components of the route. So starting with `authentication.hasValidApiKey`, that's a function defined in another file:

```
exports.hasTokenOrApi = (req, res, next) ->
  if not req.headers.authorization
    return res.status(403).end()

  doOtherStuff...
```

In my test, I have:

```
authentication = require '../src/middlewares/authentication'

describe 'Authentication Middleware', ->
  before (done) ->
    done()

  it 'should check for authentication', (done) ->
    mock_req = null
    mock_res = null
    mock_next = null

    authentication.hasTokenOrApi mock_res, mock_req, mock_next
    done()
```

How do I deal with the req, res and next? And how can I setup code coverage to run? I am running my tests with: `export NODE_ENV=test && ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers coffee:'./node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register'`

Comment: Use supertest https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

Comment: I don't believe `supertest`  will let me get code coverage, will it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple code coverage tools, many with integrations in different build systems (gulp, grunt, etc..).

One of the leading one's is [Istanbul](https://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/) which is what I personally use.  Other popular libraries are [blankets](http://blanketjs.org/)  and [coveralls](https://github.com/cainus/node-coveralls)

To see an example setup using Gulp and Istanbul (and mocha), check out [this gist I have](https://gist.github.com/789e056717927ad7a9f0.git)

Basically, you can just run through your test directory, pipe each test file through istanbul, then mocha, and have a coverage report generated if desired.

```
gulp.src(['test/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(istanbul({includeUntested: true})) // Covering files
    .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire()) // Force `require` to return covered files
    .on('finish', function () {
        gulp.src(['test/**/*.js'])
            .pipe(mocha())
            .pipe(istanbul.writeReports(
                {
                    dir: './coverage',
                    reporters: ['html', 'lcov', 'json', 'text', 'text-summary', 'cobertura']
                })) // Creating the reports after tests runned
            .on('end', cb);
    });
```

In regards to how to test just the Routing (assuming it's decoupled in a separate file or module), this can be kind of tricky.  I have similar questions posted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/express-js/iBF8B4gIHJY) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990887/unit-test-express-route-calls-controller-method).

But essentially what you're asking in the above code calls for a stub of `req` and a spy of `res.status(403).end()`.  The spy can be a bit tricky because you basically need to spy on the actual Response object in express (can google around their docs to see how to get it).

If you're not already familiar, I'd suggest using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) , but there's also other libraries for mock/stub/spies.

It seems many in the community just use Supertest and call it a day, but to me that would make it an integration test.  A true unit test would make you isolate the specific section you're trying to test.