# What does app.listen look like when using npm start

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, supertest

So this is what I was doing before I exported the `app` variable so I can perform `unit and integration testing` for `node/express` app

**app.js**

```
//app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))

module.exports = app;
```

**Now**

How do I start the server now? I was trying to move it to `package.json` file in the

```
"scripts": {"start": "app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')" }
```

so I can do:

```
npm start
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. You can have a `index.js` who will start your app, like this:

**index.js**

```
import app from './app'

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

And your script start should be:

```
"scripts": {"start": "node index.js" }
```

Like this, you can use your module `app` in your tests, and your application will work properly.

Now, just run:

```
npm start
```

If you wan't to do unit and integration tests, take a look at these links:

- [How does one unit test routes with Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517880/how-does-one-unit-test-routes-with-express)
- https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/how-to-correctly-unit-test-express-server/